# How can someone else connect to my Websocket server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

Using [this module](https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket) i'm making a websocket server on my pc.

Problem is: How do I let people connect into it? I know how to connect it from LAN(which is using ws:LANip:Port, for example:192.168.0.7:8000) but what if someone not connected in the same router, from another country(for example) wants to connect?

EDIT: And I tried using MyIP:Port but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You application should be in Internet inorder for people to connect to it. You should get a public server and host the app there. Or use cloud solutions like AWS, Azure, GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ngrok` or `localtunnel`. Both of them are free.

https://github.com/bubenshchykov/ngrok

https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel

To expose your local port 8000 for instance:

```
npm install ngrok -g
ngrok http 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

When someone tries to connect to your external IP, they talk to your router. Your router needs to know which computer on its network to connect the external connection to. This is known as [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). To find out how to do it, do a Google search for "<your router model> port forward", but first read about port forwarding in general to understand the concept itself thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you. it was a really simple question but I had no idea how to solve it. Now I know what to put in the docs of my app to help others that use it.